# Speed up compilation with mockito on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mockito, dalvik

I am currently developing an android app in eclipse using:

- One project for the app
- One project for the tests (Instrumentation and Pojo tests)

In the test project, I am importing the mockito library for standard POJO testing.
However, when I import the library, the compilation time skyrockets from 1 second to about 30 seconds in eclipse. The cause seems to be that the whole library is converted each time. So basically, each time a make a modification that I want to test, I have to wait 30 seconds.

The only workarounds that I have found so far would be:

- Disable "Build Automatically"
- Create a project that includes only pojo tests and put mockito only there.
- Use another library that compiles faster (e.g. easymock)

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the test project to be an android project?
If can get aware with creating a Java project and mocking out any of the android specific classes for the tests that would be my suggestion.

Have a look at this article:
https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/